# How can we list all files and folders recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, apache-commons-io, file-listing

As search via google, and in this SO site, results will come up with `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs()` method from Apache Commons IO.

But this method is not going recursively into sub folders - we need recursive file listing.

How can we do it with Commons IO?

P.S.:

A native way to do it is using `File.listFiles()` natively supported by JDK as solved [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/list-files-and-directories-recursively-in-a-directory).

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Commons IO?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking for an existing API which lists files recursively???

Comment: @Strikeskids For the sake of simple call indeed. I just want it short.

Comment: @Codebender Not with the existing API - already mentioned as the native way using File.listFiles()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `FileUtils.listFiles(File base, String[] extensions, boolean recursive)`.

To retrieve all of the files set `recursive` to `true` and `extensions` to `null`.

```
 FileUtils.listFiles(basePath, null, true);
```

Alternatively, using the other overides of `FileUtils.listFiles`, you can provide more detailed search parameters.

If you want to find both files AND directories instead of only files, use the

```
 FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(File directory, IOFileFilter fileFilter, IOFileFilter dirFilter)
```

See [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFilesAndDirs(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter) for more detail.

- The `dirFilter` argument sets which directories the search will recurse on. To recurse on all subdirectories use `TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE`. To NOT recurse at all, just base `null`.
- The `fileFilter` arguments chooses the files and directories the search will return. To return all of them, use `TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE`.

Example call

```
FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(basePath, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)
```

Comment: What to put in the extensions array to get all files/folders @Strikeskids?

Comment: the `extentions` set to `null`.

Comment: I tried `null` and still, just files are listed - not the folder/containing folder itself :(

Comment: Oh you'll want to use the listFilesAndDirs then... I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks so much for your clarification. Though I tried and still the containing/empty folders are NOT listed. You may try on my test folder here https://www.dropbox.com/s/htqr064i4xtda4s/snsiTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: We want to see empty folder to appear in the list.

Comment: The line of code I provided lists files for me:

Given this directory `. ./a ./b ./b/d ./c`

The provided code lists the files `[/tmp/testdir, /tmp/testdir/a, /tmp/testdir/b, /tmp/testdir/b/d, /tmp/testdir/c]`

Notice that the empty folder a appears in the output. Could you provide an example of how this didn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82373/discussion-between-strikeskids-and-nam-g-vu).

Comment: I have double checked and it works - my fault as using `listFiles()` instead of `listFilesAndDirs()`

Comment: Thank you very much for great support @Strikekids